# Is it possible in Yup to define when to validate on field basis?

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

You can define on Yup when a validation occurs. Is it possible to define the time of validation per-field? I mean, I want to validate all fields whenever there is a change on those fields, but I want to validate a certain field only when a submit happens (or when that field has lost focus). Use case is to check whether a chosen user-name is unique.